# Send date to API and get a response using Rest Template

Tags: java, api, date, resttemplate

I have to developing my first Java program which will send Date value to API and it would send back response.
If the response is null, nothing to be done. If the response a Date value, it is a holiday.
This is the model class

```
Public class Calendar holiday {
private Date calendar_date;
private String description;
}
```

I tried to use rest template with the execute method, im not sure if this method would send the date value and get a response callback.

```
public Date getHolidayVisApi(Date businessDate){
RestTemplate restTemplate= new RestTemplate;
return restTemplate.execute(url,Http method.GET,...);}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible. You can try something like this,

```
public Date getHolidayVisApi(Date businessDate){
    
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        String resourceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/allholidays";
    
        // Set HTTP headers in the request callback
        RequestCallback requestCallback = request -> {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                mapper.writeValue(request.getBody(), 
                        businessDate);

                request.getHeaders()
                 .setAccept(Arrays.asList(
                         MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, 
                         MediaType.ALL));
                };

        // Processing the response. Here we are extracting the 
        // response and copying the file to a folder in the server.
        ResponseExtractor<Void> responseExtractor = response -> {
                 Path path = Paths.get("c:/Users/smilyFace/Documents/response.txt");
                 Files.copy(response.getBody(), path);
                 return null;
             };

        restTemplate.execute(resourceUrl, 
            HttpMethod.GET, 
            requestCallback, 
            responseExtractor );    
}
```